# How to access Weblogic( on Virtual box) URL by external IP?

Tags: java, web, server, weblogic, virtualbox

I've installed on weblogic on virtual box . It is working fine if I access it by Hostname . 
But, Weblogic URL has to be accessible from cloud machine which is outside my network . Could some one help me how to make weblogic URL accessible by External IP ?.
Appreciate your help .

Thanks ,
Anilbabu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing, you host machine should be accessible from cloud. Then we can make as you asked.

Could you please let me know which networking type you are using. 
If it is NAT, then add **port forwarding rules** for ADMIN and Managed server ports.
SO cloud machine can access using your host machine IP.

Ex:

```
http://hostip:7001/em

http://hostip:7003/em
```

If you are using Bridged network, then host and guest will be in same network so that cloud machine can access

http://guestip/7001/em

Check out my blog for more info.

http://trainenv.blogspot.in/2016/03/virtual-networking.html